# How to share a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that edits text. Normally there is an id used instead of a class. I've changed it to a class because I'd like to share a single instance. Now that it's a class, I can't tell which element the user clicked on.

I want to use one instance of the following code and send in an additional argument that can be passed to my PHP that distinguishes the element and pass that to my PHP code.

```
$(".edit").edit({
  url:'server.php'
});
```

So, maybe something like:

```
function myFunc(arg){
  $(".edit").edit({
    url:'server.php?arg='+arg
  });
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work because I need the click function and I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like what you are asking for:

```
 $(".edit").click( function() { 
     $(this).edit({    
         url: 'server.php?arg=' + $(this).attr('id')
     });
 })
```

Comment: I don't recognize the edit() method for jQuery, so I am relying on your code for that to work. Hopefully you have a plugin for it.

Comment: Thanks Sam! I've got it now. Thank you again!

Comment: Does the element that gets clicked on have an id? what does the edit method expect? More code please...

Comment: No, Sam, that was my problem. Once I added the id, it worked perfectly. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Sam, what does `this` refer to?

Comment: In jQuery, "this" is a keyword which can be used in instance methods to refer to the object on which the currently executing method has been invoked.

Comment: OK, thank you for that explanation. I'll have to read more about this. It sounds like PHPs `this` keyword.

Comment: @Muzz - Javascript's `this` keyword is a bit like `this` in other languages, but in some ways very different. What it is within a function depends on how that function was called, but jQuery ensures it is set to something sensible for all standard jQuery function callbacks.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Thanks. Is there a link you can point me to that will give me more info on this? Maybe a good tutorial on JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".edit").click( function() { 
  $(this).edit({    
    url:'server.php?arg='+arg
  });
})
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks Greg. What I see when I try that is: `arg=[object Object]`. How do I get the value? Yes, this is what I am after.

Comment: what are you trying to acquire? The text instead the div/p/span with the class edit? If so then change the url line to: url:'server.php?arg='+$(this).val()

Comment: I need something to identify the element the user clicked on so that I can parse it in PHP. I've already made the change you suggested but I don't get the value I entered; it's just null.

Comment: arg is the element that was clicked on, so arg is a jQuery object. Use the appropriate method to get the data that you need. For a text input  control, .val() is correct. For a span, use .text() instead. You can also get attributes, like the element id - .attr('id')

Comment: OK, please forgive me because I'm really new to JQuery. I think I may see my problem. You're right Sam, arg is the element the user clicked on but I don't have arg set in my html. Would I set that as an id?